# Create a list of all loaded Rasters in a for loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, merge, raster

I want to merge 3252 .hgt SRTM raster using the mosaic_rasters function from rgdal, therefore i need a list of all my raster files.

I started to load all my raster files into my Global Environment using following for loop:

```
list_SRTM3_Africa <- list.files("C://.../01_data/01_SRTM/version2_1_SRTM3/Africa")

for(i in list_SRTM3_Africa) { 
  assign(unlist(strsplit(i, "[.]"))[1], raster(i))
  }
```

But unfortunately i could not figure out how to create a list from the loaded grids.

And i can not do it like this for all 3252 files:

```
raster_list_SRTM3_Africa <- c(S01E006, S01E007,..., S35E0253)
```

Then i create a large empty Raster witch i want to fill with the mosaic_rasters command.

```
 template <- raster(extent_Africa_canvas)
    projection(template) <- coord_ref_Africa_canvas
    writeRaster(template, file="SRTM3_Africa.tif", format="GTiff")

mosaic_rasters(gdalfile=raster(raster_list_SRTM3_Africa),dst_dataset="SRTM3_Africa.tif",of="GTiff", output_Raster = T)
gdalinfo("SRTM3_Africa.tif")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using the append command.

```
raster_list <- c() # initialise the list of rasters
for(i in list_SRTM3_Africa) { 
  raster_list <- append(raster_list,  assign(unlist(strsplit(i, "[.]"))[1], raster(i)))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lapply` for tasks like that

```
library(raster)
list_SRTM3_Africa <- list.files("C://.../01_data/01_SRTM/version2_1_SRTM3/Africa")

rlist <- lapply(list_SRTM3_Africa, raster)
```

Generally, you can then do something like:

```
x <- do.call(merge, rlist)
```